# JavaScript for showing and hiding divs in a timed order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I am having problems getting my code to work right.  I know I have asked this question a few times, but I really need some input on it.  Thanks to the someone on this site, I was able to get the code to work in jsFiddle, but not in my browser.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion1">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion2">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion3">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion4">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
   To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.&nbsp
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion5">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
    &nbsp;Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.
</div>

<div class="fader tutorial" id="createquestion6">
    <div class="arrow-w" style="font-size:1em;"></div>
   Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.&nbsp;
</div>

<input type="button" value="Start" id="start"/>
```

JS

```
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 500;

    function showDiv() {
        divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 5 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds     };

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    }); });​
```

CSS

```
#start{
    right:1em;
    top:1em;
    padding:1em;
}

.tutorial {
    display: table;
    border: 4px solid #8C3087;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 2px #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 11px;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    background-color:#ECA100;
    width:200;
    z-index:2000;
    font-size:12pt; 
    color:#000;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.arrow-n,
.arrow-e,
.arrow-s,
.arrow-w {
  /*
   * In Internet Explorer, The"border-style: dashed" will never be
   * rendered unless "(width * 5) >= border-width" is true.
   * Since "width" is set to "0", the "dashed-border" remains
   * invisible to the user, which renders the border just like how
   * "border-color: transparent" renders.
   */
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.53em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
  /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

.arrow-n {
    border-bottom-width: 1em;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #8C3087;
    bottom: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-e {
    border-left-width: 1em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #8C3087;
    left: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-s {
    border-top-width: 1em;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #8C3087;
    top: 0.25em;
}

.arrow-w {
    border-right-width: 1em;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #8C3087;
    right: 0.25em;
}

/* Create Multiple Choice Question */
#createquestion1 {
    top:140px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion2 {
    top:240px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion3 {
    top:340px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion4 {
    top:60px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:right !important; 
}
#createquestion5 {
    top:520px;
    left:320px;
    text-align:left;
}
#createquestion6 {
    top:140px;
    left:100px;
    text-align:right !important;
}
```

Lots ups to anyone who can help me!  The page I am working in is an asp.  I am open to new ideas also.  Ideally, I would love to make this happen entirely in CSS3...​

Comment: Please make a reduced test case in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @zzzzBov This works on fiddle and you can see the result I am going for.  http://jsfiddle.net/NpNXr/6/

Comment: `Thanks to the someone on this site, I was able to get the code to work in jsFiddle, but not in my browser` Does your browser show any errors in the browser console log? What browser and version are you testing on? Have you included in your browser the required jQuery files? Can you elaborate on `not working`? If you intend a full CSS3 solution what browser are you targeting? Not all CSS3 transformations/animations, etc. are supported in all browsers.

Comment: seriously... what does "not working" mean? what exactly is the result of your above code, and what are you expecting the result of the above code to be?

Answer (score 0):

Working code: :-)

```
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
fadeLoop()
function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').hide(),
        dur = 300;

    function showDiv() {
        $("div.fader").fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 7 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<% if Request("interactive") = "on" then %>
<form name="tutorial">

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation1" style="font-size:1em;" ></div><div id="tutorial1" class="tutorial createquestion1">Start by creating a title and selecting a folder for your question to be stored in.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation2" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial2" class="tutorial createquestion2">Categories are key to your reporting effectiveness, be sure to include categories that relate to this question.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation3" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial3" class="tutorial createquestion3">Select your options and/or upload an attachment (file, video or audio).</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation4">QUICK TIP</div><div class="arrow-n arrowlocation4" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial4" class="quicktip createquestion4">To create questions easier update your question preferences in your account area options.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation5" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial5" class="tutorial createquestion5">Your rationale can be used to provide feedback to students on this question and you also can use internal comment to track notes on changes, updates, textbook information and more.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-e arrowlocation6" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div id="tutorial6" class="tutorial createquestion6">Write your questions, answers and you are ready to go.</div></div>

<div class="fader"><div class="arrow-w arrowlocation7" style="font-size:1em;" ></div>
<div class="quicktiptitle quicktiplocation7">QUICK TIP</div>
<div id="tutorial7" class="quicktip createquestion7"> Click on this icon to open and close sections that you don't use. These will remain closed whenever you visit this page until you open them again.</div></div></form>


<% end if %>
```